# Setting header size in PDFKit with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, header, pdfkit

I need a repeating image to be shown on every page of the pdf. The only solution to this I've found so far is putting it into the header using

`%meta{:name => 'pdfkit-header_html', :content => pdf_header_url}`

Works fine but the image is bigger than the header size. Is there any way I can increase the height of the header or put a repeating image somehow outside the header?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding this code

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|
  config.default_options = {
    :page_size     => 'Letter',
    :margin_top    => '3.6in',
    :margin_right  => '0.3in',
    :margin_bottom => '1.3in',
    :margin_left   => '0.3in'
  }
end
```

to /config/initializers/pdfkit.rb. Worked like charm after I restarted the server.

Comment: If using only some of these, you may need to use "mm" instead of inches.  I found this with trial and error, when the error said "all units must be the same" - without indicating what units it had encountered.  I had set no units, elsewhere - so perhaps 'mm' is the default.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to tweak the `margin-top` and `header-spacing` values. For example:

```
%meta{:name => 'pdfkit-header_html', :content => pdf_header_url}
%meta{:name => 'pdfkit-margin_top', :content => '3cm' }
%meta{:name => 'pdfkit-header_spacing', :content => '10' }
```

From [the wkhtmltopdf docs](https://github.com/antialize/wkhtmltopdf/blob/master/README_WKHTMLTOPDF):

```
--header-spacing * <real>         Spacing between header and content in mm
                                  (default 0)
-T, --margin-top <unitreal>       Set the page top margin (default 10mm)
```

You can put any of the wkpdftohtml options in the meta tags and PDFKit will pass them through.